# Error saving data from textbox to sql server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, ado.net

I have created a WPF desktop application before and I was able to write up the code to save data from a textbox to a table I created in sql server 2012. I tried to create a WPF Web browser application and the same code was not working to save my data to my sql database. I am now trying to create another WPF desktop application and the same code that worked the last time is not working anymore. Please look at my code and help.

```
private void savebuyers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string connectionstring = null;
        connectionstring = "Data Source=FRANCIS;Initial Catalog=Pam Golding;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

        try
        {
            string query;
            query = "insert into buyers (name,number,email) values ('" + namebuyers.Text + "'," + Convert.ToInt32(numberbuyers) + ",'" + emailbuyers.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            message1.Text = "Data Saved Successfully!";
            con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            message1.Text = "Error While Saving Data!";
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: use `catch (Exception ex)` and set the `Text` of your `message1` element to `ex.Message` instead. This should help you to identify what the error is.

Comment: By not working I mean that my catch{} is always executed each time.

Comment: @FrancisMbiriri That means, you have an exception in your `try` block. What exception you get? On which line? What are your values?

Comment: @SonerGönül I am new to c#. Please help me on how to find out what the exception is. When I debug, I enter random values that would work if I query the database directly in sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `Text` property of `numberbuyers`. So it is unable to cast object of type `TextBox` to type `System.IConvertible`.
You can fix it like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(numberbuyers.Text)
```

Also you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [`Sql Injection`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).